# Building emacs with native compilation on Apple M1

Tags: osx

I am using the homebrew-emacs-head recipe to 'brew' a bleeding edge Emacs once a week. I just moved to Emacs 29 on my Intel mac, and decided to try native compilation. After a little bit of fiddling with LIBRARY_PATH in `early-init.el`, it works wonderfully.

Now I'm trying the same thing on an M1 MBP. Regular build of this recipe works fine. But native comp with or without AOT does not build. It fails early in the process for autoconf and configure:

```
==> ./configure --enable-locallisppath=/opt/homebrew/share/emacs/site-lisp --infodir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-head@28/28.0.60_1/share/info/emacs --prefix=
Last 15 lines from /Users/jcm/Library/Logs/Homebrew/emacs-head@28/02.configure:
--with-gnutls
--with-rsvg
--with-xml2
--with-ns
--disable-ns-self-contained

checking for xcrun... xcrun
checking for make... yes
checking for GNU Make... make
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/emacs-headA28-20211028-42351-1ck4isv':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

---

Given that I've installed Xcode 13.1 and the command line tools and built other recipes without issue, what might be the issue here?

Here are some relevant lines from config.log:

```
configure:5850: checking whether the C compiler works  
configure:5872: clang -O2 -march=native -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/include  -L/opt/homebrew/lib/gcc/11 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libg  
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'  
configure:5876: $? = 1  
configure:5916: result: no  
configure: failed program was:  
| /* confdefs.h */  
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU Emacs"  
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "emacs"  
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "28.0.60"  
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU Emacs 28.0.60"  
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org"  
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/"  
| #define HAVE_PDUMPER 1  
| /* end confdefs.h.  */  
.
.
.
configure:5923: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: Follow the instructions in the error message, and find the actual errors from the compiler. They are in a file called `config.log`. Add them to your question.

Comment: your `clang` doesn't support flag `-march=native`

Comment: @nega Yes, I was able to deduce that as well. The next step is how to fix it, since emacs obviously can be compiled on arm64.

Comment: https://cpufun.substack.com/p/setting-up-the-apple-m1-for-native

Comment: if you just want to disable `-march` or change it, have you tried setting CFLAGS yourself?

Comment: I'm building this via a brew recipe, so I haven't dug down to where I'd be able to set CFLAGS, not to mention this is for native compilation so that might make it even harder to find.

Comment: `CFLAGS="-02 -march=MYSUPPORTEDARCH" ./configure` for any autotools recipie. setting the environment in a homebrew recipe is easy enough via `brew edit`. there's even an example in the emacs recipe!

Comment: Thanks @nega, that did the trick! I didn't know about the 'edit' feature of brew, and that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @nega - I think this is on-topic enough - regardless of whether it is on topic or not, please don't answer in the comments - get the answers into an answer.

Comment: @AaronHall they're not intended to be answers

Comment: @jmckitrick alternatively, you could write up an answer to your question that makes these comments obsolete...